# How can I make this infinite carousel work?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, carousel, infinite-carousel

I have this carousel that needs a simple operation: appear infinite. The problem is that the animation cuts off and leaves a blank space at the end of the last element. I leave the code below and hope someone can help me.

```css
.slider {
    padding-top: 28px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 40px;
    animation: scroll 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {

    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}

.slider-items img {
    width: 12%;
    margin: 40px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="slider pb-12">
  <div className="slider-items">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried cloning the content, using sass, changing the seconds the animation lasts, the width of all the containers, changing the HTML structure and nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added images and a container (which you were missing I think).

Pay attention to the 100% keyframe where half of the flex gap (or maybe half of the parent padding ? well you should test it :D) must be taken into account if you want the the animation to look smooth :)

```css
.slider {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
}
.slider-items-container {
  display: contents;
  
}
.slider-items {
  gap: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(calc(-50% - 10px));
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-items-container">
    <div class="slider-items">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/psd-gratuit/lettres-argent-facade-du-batiment-verre_145275-162.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.1546980028.1711411200&semt=sph" alt="" />
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_B%C3%BCrogeb%C3%A4ude_--_2013_--_5149-51.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5VDK6xeSfkbgUbiwQPLF6sxWYBrQTfcgyn6qUv4l11w&s" alt="" />
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/178447404/fr/photo/b%C3%A2timents-daffaires-moderne.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=KDgacnz516dO2YiaMsiyHABoHaBhv5K1CRjHUEbcviQ=" alt="" />
      <img src="https://images.lawpath.com.au/2020/06/sean-pollock-PhYq704ffdA-unsplash-scaled.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHsRbGBlz2CdOJ0WmplUX-0zqZ-jqG3JY74W7OyCG6EA&s" alt="" />
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/psd-gratuit/lettres-argent-facade-du-batiment-verre_145275-162.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.1546980028.1711411200&semt=sph" alt="" />
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_B%C3%BCrogeb%C3%A4ude_--_2013_--_5149-51.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5VDK6xeSfkbgUbiwQPLF6sxWYBrQTfcgyn6qUv4l11w&s" alt="" />
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/178447404/fr/photo/b%C3%A2timents-daffaires-moderne.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=KDgacnz516dO2YiaMsiyHABoHaBhv5K1CRjHUEbcviQ=" alt="" />
      <img src="https://images.lawpath.com.au/2020/06/sean-pollock-PhYq704ffdA-unsplash-scaled.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHsRbGBlz2CdOJ0WmplUX-0zqZ-jqG3JY74W7OyCG6EA&s" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```